# JCR avoid file streaming

Tags: binary, java-io, jackrabbit, jcr

In my jackrabbit datastore there are large binary files stored.
I can browse the datastore filesystem and open these files without any problems.

Now how can I use these files from within my application? I of course could use the
        getStream() method of type jcr.binary but then I would just stream all the content of the already exsisting file into a new temporary file right? Since my binarys are very large I don't want that. I'm looking for a way to get the full filesystem path of a binary. The method
        getpath() of jcr.Property only returns the path within the repository and only with the mapped node names and not the node names which are really stored on my filesystem. In general I have to parse a binary object into a Java.IO.File object and I want to avoid Streaming

Edit: Through reflection I saw that the class of my binary is 
        class org.apache.jackrabbit.core.value.BLOBInDataStore I guess I have to somehow access the File value from there

Comment: What makes you think that `getStream()` creates temporary files?

Comment: not getStream() itself but to use it I have to read in every byte into memory

Comment: And what do you want to do with those blobs that does not involve reading them into memory?

Comment: I want to get the absolute filepath (not only within the datastore) of the blob and pass it as an argument to an external programm. Is there a way (maybe through reflection) to get to this path from an exisiting filestream? Because somewhere the filestream has to get the information from where to stream the bytes...

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a good idea. You're bypassing access control , transactions, versioning and perhaps others and giving direct access to the datastore. Think of it like using an external program to read the MySQL InnoDB data files. Which leads me to the point, you're locked into never using a data store manager which does not write in the format you expect to the filesystem.

Comment: Well I use a persistence manager to store uploaded files in the datastore. Also the files which are created through the external program are stored with this manager using the jcr 2.0 api so I can control the format. It's just that I the external program exspects the filepath of a blob as an argument and I since loading in memory a 2GB+ blob is not feasible I guess I have to bypass features like access control, transactions and so on and choose the lesser of the two evils don't you think?

Comment: You might not want to use the JCR API to pass files to an external system - a WebDAV mount (out of the box with Jackrabbit) or HTTP is probably simpler. If you mount your JCR repository via WebDAV, for example, you'll see your files at the same paths than in the JCR tree.

Comment: That sounds very good. Does this work with the jca resource adapter version of jackrabbit too or do I have to use the standalone server?

Comment: Edit: I think we misunderstood here... The repository isn't running on an external system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right when saying that reflection could be of help. Here's my code which returns the physical filepath of a binary stored in a jackrabbit datastore :

```
public String getPhysicalBinaryPath(Binary b){
    try {
        Field idField=b.getClass().getDeclaredField("identifier");
        idField.setAccessible(true);
        String identifier = (String)idField.get(b).toString();
        Field storeField=b.getClass().getDeclaredField("store");
        storeField.setAccessible(true);
        Object store = storeField.get(b);
        Field pathField = store.getClass().getDeclaredField("path");
        pathField.setAccessible(true);
        String dataStorePath = (String)pathField.get(store);

        String binaryPath = identifier.substring(0,2)+File.separator+
                            identifier.substring(2,4)+File.separator+
                            identifier.substring(4,6)+File.separator+
                            identifier;

        return dataStorePath+File.separator+binaryPath;

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Repoutput.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Repoutput.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Repoutput.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Repoutput.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

        return "";


}
```

Edit: This is the official way to do it (you'll have to use the jackrabbit-api)

```
Binary b = session.getValueFactory().createBinary(in);
Value value = session.getValueFactory().createValue(b);
  if (value instanceof JackrabbitValue) {
   JackrabbitValue jv = (JackrabbitValue) value;
   String id = jv.getContentIdentity();
  }
```